# Undefined variable "SLAM" or class "SLAM.Utils.checkForMultiRunnableASModel"

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a model that runs fine in Normal mode but when I change to Accelerator I get a strange error which I can't really figure out how to proceed with.

I've searched some for this but I can't find anything about it. I have no calls or any connection to any class named SLAM in my model, so I think it has something to do with Matlab/Simulink. SLAM = SimuLinkAcceleratorMode?

Does anyone have any idea how to continue with this?

Message: Build Error
Source: modelname
Reported By: Simulink
Summary: Undefined variable "SLAM" or class "SLAM.Utils.checkForMultiRunnableASModel".

Message: Model Error
Source: modelname
Reported By: Simulink
Summary: Problem creating Accelerator MEX file for model 'modelname'.

Caused by:
Undefined variable "SLAM" or class "SLAM.Utils.checkForMultiRunnableASModel".

Comment: Never seen this before and a Google/MathWorks search doesn't yield anything. Might be better off contacting MathWorks tech support directly: http://uk.mathworks.com/support/servicerequests/index.html

Comment: I did a C: search on my PC and found that this is probably related to the AUTOSAR Target Production Package toolbox installed